# How do I use Firebase Admin SDK Service Key JSON file in a remote Linux shell (Python Admin SDK)?

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-admin

I recently got started with Firebase, and I had a question about the private key JSON file. I can download it and securely store the file on a computer that has a GUI - and so my Firebase Admin SDK code works fine on computers with a GUI. However, I can't get the file to work on a remote Linux shell, as when I copy the certificate contents over to a .json file on the shell, it throws errors relating to the JSON formatting.

How would I use the use the Admin SDK for Python on a remote Linux server with no access to a GUI, as I can't download the private key file (as it requires a GUI to download)? Thanks in advance.

Edit: I forgot to add what's causing the problem. The code I'm trying to run is here (I'm trying to use the Admin SDK for Python):

```py
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import db
   
firebase_admin.initialize_app({
     'databaseURL' : '<database URL here>'
})
    
ref = db.reference('/')
print(ref.get())
```

Below is the template for the service account private key generated by Firebase when clicking on the "Generate Private Key" button in the Firebase service account settings (I've removed the values for security reasons):

```
{
  "type": "",
  "project_id": "",
  "private_key_id": "",
  "private_key": "",
  "client_id": "",
  "auth_uri": "",
  "token_uri": "",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "",
  "client_x509_cert_url": ""
}
```

I've set the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` variable to the file path of the private key file. This works with the Windows machine, but on my Linux backend, I get this error if I copy the contents of my private key to a .json file on the Linux backend:

> ValueError: Illegal Firebase credential provided. App must be initialized with a valid credential instance.

How should I use the Admin SDK with a remote Linux server with no access to a GUI? Thanks.

Comment: "*it throws errors relating to the JSON formatting.*" - please edit the question to explain in more detail what you're doing that doesn't work the way you expect. Are you running code?  Show it.  If there are errors, your question should show those as well.

Comment: Sorry, updated.